# UIKit: Infinitely Scrollable Card with rows (as seen in Snapchat or Duolingo)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit

I would like to implement an UI element as shown on the screenshots:

[image: Duolingo] [image: Snapchat]

Image 1: **Duolingo**

Image2: **Snapchat**

The UI element consists of a card having a size slightly smaller than the screen.

The card's content, made up of rows (like in UITableView) can fit the screen fully. In this case, a card with all the rounded corners is shown.

If the card's content doesn't fit the screen fully, it can be scrolled. The content of the card could be of arbitrary length. In this case, a card shows the rounded corners only on the last elements.

**Advanced challenge**
Add a shadow behind each card.

**Questions**

1. What UI components to pick for this problem
2. A way to combine the UI components, preferably with the background shadow support. Note, that the apps on the screenshots do not have shadow.

Comment: In what way does `UITableView` not work for you?

Comment: It works well, until the "shadow" part.